# "Invalid general config setting: useProjectConfigFile..." when Upgrading

Tags: install

Working through the upgrade docs, and when I run `php craft migrate/all` I get the following:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Invalid general config setting: useProjectConfigFile. You can set custom config settings from config/custom.php.'

in /home/user/smw_craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/GeneralConfig.php:3086
```

Kinda stuck. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useProjectConfigFile` config setting was deprecated in Craft 3.5 (and has done nothing since), and was finally completely removed in Craft 4.0.

**To fix that error, remove any traces of the `useProjectConfigFile` config setting from your `config/general.php` file.**

Note that if you previously had this setting set to `false`, it could be a good idea to familiarise yourself with [the changes Craft 3.5 brought to project config](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/upgrading-to-craft-3-5#project-config-workflow) (it has seen no significant changes since, so this is still current info, as of Craft 4.3).

Also good to know, is that the real reason you're getting that exception, is that Craft 4 is more strict about what you can put in the `config/general.php` file. **In Craft 4 any setting in that file that isn't actually a [core config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html) – either because it has been removed from core at some point like `useProjectConfigFile`, or because it's a custom setting – will throw that error.**

*If you have any custom config settings in your `general.php` file that you want to retain, you can move them to a `config/custom.php` file, as per [the official upgrade guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/upgrade.html#config-settings).*

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks for the extra info. Helped a lot.